# Iphone development resources

Tags: ios

I've started to play with the IPhone SDK. What are the best resources to get started? (books, tutorials, blogs?)

Comment: As splattne notes, this is pretty similar to the question he links to, so I've added my answer to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apple iPhone developer site:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/
Another link: http://www.iphonedevcentral.org/

Answer (score 3):

You can find answers to a similar question here on StackOverflow:

[Howto articles for iPhone development, Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)